# Is it less load on Redis to do srandmember [key] 5 over 5 separate queries?

Tags: redis

In a case where Redis `SRANDMEMBER` on a set is being called potentially multiple times (unknown at run time), does it reduce the load on the Redis server to use

`SRANDMEMBER [key] count`

instead of running

`SRANDMEMBER [key] 1`, count number of times?

For example, running it for `srandmember [key] 5` when we know there will never be more than 5 random members needed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on lots of things...

First of all, let's call `SRANDMEMBER [key] 1` as `SRANDMEMBER`, while call `SRANDMEMBER [key] count` as `batch SRANDMEMBER`. Also `SRANDMEMBER [key] 1` is equal to `SRANDMEMBER [key]`.

> How many random members do you want?

If you need too many random members, i.e. a very large `count`, then `batch SRANDMEMBER` might block the server for a long time, since Redis is *single-threaded*. And that increases the load of Redis.

On the contrary, if `count` is small, e.g. less than `10`, `batch SRANDMEMBER` should be very efficient, and does NOT increase any significant load.

> Network latency

Compared to multiple calls to `SRANDMEMBER` (multiple 'RTT'), `batch SRANDMEMBER` can reduce network latency, i.e. only cost a single `RTT`.

> Unique random members

With multiple calls to `SRANDMEMBER`, you might get the same member multiple times.

If you want unique random members, you have to use `batch SRANDMEMBER`. If `count` is positive, Redis guarantees that the returned members are unique. Of course, the number of returned members might be smaller than `count`, if `count` is larger than the size of the `SET`.

If your system is tolerant with duplicated random members, you can use either multiple calls to `SRANDMEMBER`, or a single call to `batch SRANDMEMBER` with a negative `count`.